# How do I make for loop wait for db promise to finish before it continues to next iteration?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im currently using node.js sequalize to extract data from database and in the frontend I am using ajax requests. So I am sending ajax request with json object to edit the database. But when I try to edit the database the foor loop doesnt wait for the promises to finish before it goes to next iteration. I tried to send the promises to array and using the Bluebird function Promise.each but the promises are executed before they are even sent to the array. What can I do so I can pause the for loop before the current promise is completed?

```
for(var i=0; i<recordsJSON.length; i++)
{
    var recordJSON = recordsJSON[i];

    Record.nullPayeeId(recordJSON.id).then(function()
    {
        return Record.getOneRecord(recordJSON.id);
    })
    .then(function(record)
    {
        var virtualPayeeId = record.virtualPayeeId;
        return VirtualPayee.deletePayee(virtualPayeeId);
    })
    .then(function()
    {
        var category = parseInt(recordsJSON[i].category);
        var subcategory = parseInt(recordsJSON[i].subcategory);

        return VirtualPayee.insertPayee({
            payee: recordJSON.payee,
            description: recordJSON.description,
            categoryId:category,
            subcategoryId:subcategory
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you meantioned Bluebird, you can use [`Promise.mapSeries()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) to help you serialize things:

```
Promise.mapSeries(recordsJSON, function(recordJSON) {
    return Record.nullPayeeId(recordJSON.id).then(function () {
        return Record.getOneRecord(recordJSON.id);
    }).then(function(record) {
        var virtualPayeeId = record.virtualPayeeId;
        return VirtualPayee.deletePayee(virtualPayeeId);
    }).then(function() {
        var category = parseInt(recordJSON.category);
        var subcategory = parseInt(recordsSON.subcategory);

        return VirtualPayee.insertPayee({
            payee: recordJSON.payee,
            description: recordJSON.description,
            categoryId: category,
            subcategoryId: subcategory
        });
    });
}).then(function (results) {
    // results here in oder
}).catch(function (err) {
    // error here
});
```

If you want to serialize them manually, then you would probably want to use the `.reduce()` pattern with your promises.  You can read about that pattern here:

[JavaScript: Perform a chain of promises synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464813/javascript-perform-a-chain-of-promises-synchronously/33464843#33464843)

[How to synchronize a sequence of promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506)

[Can Promise load multi urls in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886555/can-promise-load-multi-urls-in-order/33887054#33887054)

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooo much. It helped me a lot. I thought mapSeries only mapped promises. I would have never seen that if it wasnt you. Thank you again!