# How to load libraries before am4core is called in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, amcharts

I have a requirement where I have to create a custom widget using Amcharts. But I am facing problem that before the libraries are loaded am4core function is called.

HTML Code

```
<com-sap-sample-helloworld5></com-sap-sample-helloworld5>
```

Js code

```
(function () {
  const amchartscorejs = "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js";
  const amchartschartsjs = "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js";
  const amchartsanimatedjs = "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js";
  const vennchartjs = "https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/venn.js";
  async function LoadLibs() {
    console.log("LoadLibs");
    try {
      await loadScript(amchartscorejs);
      await loadScript(amchartschartsjs);
      await loadScript(amchartsanimatedjs);
      await loadScript(vennchartjs);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    } finally {
      that._firstConnection = 1;
    }
  }
  LoadLibs();
  function loadScript(src) {
    console.log("LoadScript");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = src;
      script.onload = () => {
        console.log("Load: " + src);
        resolve(script);
      };
      script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
  }
  let template = document.createElement("template");
  template.innerHTML = `<div id="chartdiv" width="100%" height="500px"></div>`;
  customElements.define(
    "com-sap-sample-helloworld5",
    class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
          mode: "open",
        });
        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        this._firstConnection = false;
        this.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          var event = new Event("onClick");
          this.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
      }
      //Fired when the widget is added to the html DOM of the page
      connectedCallback() {
        this._firstConnection = true;
        this.redraw();
      }
      //Fired when the widget is removed from the html DOM of the page (e.g. by hide)
      disconnectedCallback() {}
      //When the custom widget is updated, the Custom Widget SDK framework executes this function first
      onCustomWidgetBeforeUpdate(oChangedProperties) {}
      //When the custom widget is updated, the Custom Widget SDK framework executes this function after the update
      onCustomWidgetAfterUpdate(oChangedProperties) {
        if (this._firstConnection) {
          this.redraw();
        }
      }
      //When the custom widget is removed from the canvas or the analytic application is closed
      onCustomWidgetDestroy() {}
      //When the custom widget is resized on the canvas, the Custom Widget SDK framework executes the following JavaScript function call on the custom widget
      // Commented out by default
      /*
    onCustomWidgetResize(width, height){
    
    }
    */
      get chartType() {
        return this.chartTypeValue;
      }
      set chartType(value) {
        this.chartTypeValue = value;
      }

      redraw() {
        console.log("redraw function");
        // Themes begin
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
        // Themes end
        var data = [
          { name: "A", value: 10 },
          {
            name: "B",
            value: 10,
          },
          {
            name: "C",
            value: 10,
          },
          {
            name: "X",
            value: 2,
            sets: ["A", "B"],
          },
          {
            name: "Y",
            value: 2,
            sets: ["A", "C"],
          },
          {
            name: "Z",
            value: 2,
            sets: ["B", "C"],
          },
          {
            name: "Q",
            value: 1,
            sets: ["A", "B", "C"],
          },
        ];

        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_venn.VennDiagram);
        var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_venn.VennSeries());
        series.dataFields.category = "name";
        series.dataFields.value = "value";
        series.dataFields.intersections = "sets";
        series.data = data;
        chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
        chart.legend.marginTop = 40;
      }
    }
  );
})();
```

Please tell what changes should I do so that first amCharts libraries are loaded and then redraw() function is called.

You can also check the logs in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashutosh181094/mfxshakg/) to understand what problem I am facing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with [Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886555/can-promise-load-multi-urls-in-order/33887054), but ended up on an [Amcharts Issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/899) that Amcharts needs to be loaded in sequence.

ES7 awaits will do the job

You were halfway there, but stopped the async part and continued with sync `loadLibs`, it looks like you then struggled trying to *flag* the element when loading was done.

Here libraries load in sequence, with a generic **loadScripts** function,
ready for multiple custom elements depending on AmCharts, script will only load once:

```js
(function() {
  function log() {
    let args = [...arguments];
    //console.log(`%c ${args.shift()} `, "background:lightgreen", ...args); //Chrome!
    document.body.append(args.join` `,document.createElement('BR'));
  }
  log("start IIFE script");
  async function loadScripts() {
    const load = (src) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = `https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/${src}.js`;
      if (document.querySelector(`[src="${script.src}"]`)) resolve();
      log("load", script.src)
      script.onload = resolve;
      //script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));
      document.head.append(script)
    });
    await load("core"); // must be loaded first
    await load("charts");
    await load("themes/animated");
    await load("plugins/venn");
    return "return not even required";
  }
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = `<div>Executing:</div>`;
      log('connectedCallback');
      loadScripts().then(result => {
        log('done loading', result);
      });
    }
  });

})();
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

You could move everything **inside** the (now `async` marked) connectedCallback

```
  async connectedCallback() {
    const load = (src) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = `https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/${src}.js`;
      //if (document.querySelector(`[src="${script.src}"]`)) resolve();
      script.onload = resolve;
      this.append(script); // fine, doesn't really matter where SCRIPT is injected
    });
    await load("core");
    await load("charts");
    await load("themes/animated");
    await load("plugins/venn");
    // Loaded all
  }
```

If the connectedCallback runs multiple times because you move DOM nodes around you need that check for already loaded script

Answer (score 0):

Move a part of a code where you are firing am4core to separate file and load it like others but change also your **loadScript** funcion to use defer:

```
 function loadScript(src)
{
console.log("LoadScript");
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
{
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.defer = true;

    script.onload = () => {console.log("Load: " + src); resolve(script);}
    script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));

    document.head.appendChild(script)
  });
}
```

BTW I think it's always better to have  tags together so change last line:

```
document.head.appendChild(script)
```

to:

```
var scriptTag = document.head.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptTag.nextSibling);
```

Comment: _"better to have tags together"_ is only for those who open F12 HTML Source.  It doesn't matter **where** you inject ``script``. You can do ``document.body.append(script)`` and have the same functional result. Only when injecting CSS is order important. Your ``getElementsByTagName`` use actually makes it worse, it creates a [**live** nodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static); you don't clear the variable, so are wasting CPU cycles.