How do I instantiate this external script from inside a custom element?
Background: Building a Wix app, got a working calendar widget going on this test site but it can't link out after selecting dates due to Wix' iframe sandboxing. They said to use a custom element instead, but I've never built one before and it's not working with no errors to debug my way through!
Demo on CodePen
For the purposes of sharing code, I've hardcoded the property ID in - normally this would come from the widget / app settings set by the website editor.
The function in question works elsewhere, for example in the iframe version that hit a dead end, or in the equivalent plugin built for WordPress.
HTML:
<bookster-wix-acw></bookster-wix-acw>
Custom Element JS:
class BooksterWixACW extends HTMLElement {
  static observedAttributes = ["propertyid"];

  constructor() {
    super();
  }


  connectedCallback() {
    var widget = document.querySelector('bookster-wix-acw');
    // var propertyID = widget.getAttribute('propertyid');
    var propertyID = '32246';
    // console.log('connectedCallback: Property ID is '+propertyID);

    const createWidgetContainer = () => {
      const widgetContainer = document.createElement("div");
      widgetContainer.id = "bookster-calendar-widget-" + propertyID;
      return widgetContainer;
    };

    widget.appendChild(createWidgetContainer());


    // This function doesn't work as expected from inside the custom element
    if(propertyID != null) {
      (function (w, d, a) {

        console.log(window);
        console.log(document);

        var b = (w.bookster = w.bookster || []);
        b.push({ calendar: a });
        var h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var j = d.createElement('script');
        j.type = 'text/javascript';
        j.async = false;
        j.src = 'https://cdn.booksterhq.com/widgets/v1/calendar.js';
        h.appendChild(j)
      })(window, document, { id: 'bookster-calendar-widget' + propertyID, property: propertyID, syndicate: 67, theme: {} });
    };
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    
    console.log(
      `attributeChangedCallback: ${name} has changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}.`
    );

    var propertyID = `${newValue}`;

    // Doing this again on attributeChangedCallback is probably not right, but was temporarily the plan
    (
      function (w, d, a) {
        console.log('attributeChangedCallback Function has ID: ' + propertyID);
        
        var b = (w.bookster = w.bookster || []);
        b.push({ calendar: a });
        var h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var j = d.createElement('script');
        j.type = 'text/javascript';
        j.async = false;
        j.src = 'https://cdn.booksterhq.com/widgets/v1/calendar.js';
        h.appendChild(j)
      })(window, document, { id: 'bookster-calendar-widget' + document.querySelector('bookster-wix-acw').getAttribute('propertyid'), property: document.querySelector('bookster-wix-acw').getAttribute('propertyid'), syndicate: 67, theme: {} });

  }
}

customElements.define("bookster-wix-acw", BooksterWixACW);```


I don't want to flag it a duplicate because this question was about loading multiple scripts in order. But you can sure take pointers from the/my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209130/how-to-load-libraries-before-am4core-is-called-in-amcharts. Note: you can remove the constructor, a non-defined constructor will execute the constructor from its parent Class (which is what super() also does)

Note: var widget = document.querySelector('bookster-wix-acw'); is your Web Component if there is only one in the DOM Then widget. is the same as this.
